# ffmpeg cli settings for the most accurate seeking in the output video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, media-player, transcode, hls

I have a problem with video encoding for HLS stream.

I've found that most video players not support frame accurate seeking or pausing at specific frame and they can't really give us the **accurate** current time of the playback. I don't really understand that, because doesn't seem too hard to figure out the current time. (AVPlayer and ExoPlayer have same problem)

**Why is it so hard to pause or seek to specific frame in a HLS (not live) stream?**
**Why can't the players give an accurate time/position information about the playback? Why is it so hard?**

I also found that **keyframes/GOP** size maybe related to this problem, because **video players will seek to the closest keyframe**.

So my question is that, can I somehow improve the seeking and current time information with a specific ffmpeg transcode settings?

Comment: If the issue is related to key frames, then transcoding to a codec that has only key frames (such as MJPEG) will probably do, but at the expanse of a huge file size (or poor quality). That said it seems to me that VLC for instance has a frame by frame advance/back capability (don't know if it displays the exact timing beyond 1 second accuracy, though)

Comment: I tried encoding with force 4 keyframe/seconds. Now the seeking and current time works well. I understand that why it could fix the seeking problem, but i can't imagine that how related the current time to the keyframes?

Comment: This is probably player dependant. When seeking along a video, some players may chose to decode only the keyframes (with their associated times) because this is faster.